# How to combine 4 png graphs into a single one in R?

Tags: r, plot, graph

I am working on a research project and I have already generated 4 graphs and exported them as png photos. Here are my graphs:
[image: Graph 1]
[image: Graph 2]
[image: Graph 3]
[image: Graph 4]

I would like to combine the 4 png files in one plot in R - something like this:
[image: Example combined graphs]

The model I am working on is a classic logistic regression and I need the four plots to graphically represent the predicted probabilities for the different values of 4 variables, whose content is comparable. Due to the fact, that I only have a limited space for plots in the word file I would like to use as few separate plots as possible. So I decided that it would be a good idea to combine the four plots into a single one, but I don't know how. What is the simplest way to combine the four graphs into one?

Just in case here is my code too:

```
m3 <-glm(d4a ~ e1 + e2 + e4 + c2a + c2b + c2c + c2g, data = dat_clear,
         family = binomial(link = "logit"), na.action = na.omit)

#Predicted probabilities & CIs c2a
df <- data.frame(e1 = mean(dat_clear$e1), e2 = mean(dat_clear$e2),
                 e4 = mean(dat_clear$e4), c2a = min(dat_clear$c2a) : max(dat_clear$c2a),
                 c2b = mean(dat_clear$c2b), c2c = mean(dat_clear$c2c), c2g = mean(dat_clear$c2g))

head(df)

se <- predict(m3, newdata = df, type = "response",
              se.fit = TRUE)
str(se)
df$prediction <- se$fit
df$se <- se$se.fit

df$lower <- df$prediction - 1.96 * df$se
df$upper <- df$prediction + 1.96 * df$se

plot(df$prediction ~ c(1:5), ylim = c(0,1), 
     pch = 19, ylab = "Predicted Probability", xlab = "Press on immigrants to adapt (c2a)",
     main = "Figure 4: Predicted Pr(Y = 1) by c2a")
segments(c(1:5), df$lower, c(1:5), df$upper)
text(x = c(1.25,4.75), par("usr")[3],labels = c("Strongly disagree","Strongly agree"),
     pos= 3)

try(dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"]),silent=TRUE)
try(dev.off(),silent=TRUE)

rm(df, se)

#Predicted probabilites & CIs c2b
df <- data.frame(e1 = mean(dat_clear$e1), e2 = mean(dat_clear$e2),
                 e4 = mean(dat_clear$e4), c2a = mean(dat_clear$c2a),
                 c2b = min(dat_clear$c2b) : max(dat_clear$c2b), c2c = mean(dat_clear$c2c), 
                 c2g = mean(dat_clear$c2g))

head(df)

se <- predict(m3, newdata = df, type = "response",
              se.fit = TRUE)
str(se)
df$prediction <- se$fit
df$se <- se$se.fit

df$lower <- df$prediction - 1.96 * df$se
df$upper <- df$prediction + 1.96 * df$se

plot(df$prediction ~ c(1:5), ylim = c(0,1), 
     pch = 19, ylab = "Predicted Probability",xlab = "Laissez-faire (c2b)",
     main = "Figure 5: Predicted Pr(Y = 1) by c2b")
segments(c(1:5), df$lower, c(1:5), df$upper)
text(x = c(1.25,4.75), par("usr")[3],labels = c("Strongly disagree","Strongly agree"),
     pos= 3)

try(dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"]),silent=TRUE)
try(dev.off(),silent=TRUE)

rm(df, se)


#Predicted probabilities & CIs c2c
df <- data.frame(e1 = mean(dat_clear$e1), e2 = mean(dat_clear$e2),
                 e4 = mean(dat_clear$e4), c2a = mean(dat_clear$c2a),
                 c2b = mean(dat_clear$c2b), c2c = min(dat_clear$c2c) : max(dat_clear$c2c), 
                 c2g = mean(dat_clear$c2g))

head(df)

se <- predict(m3, newdata = df, type = "response",
              se.fit = TRUE)
str(se)
df$prediction <- se$fit
df$se <- se$se.fit

df$lower <- df$prediction - 1.96 * df$se
df$upper <- df$prediction + 1.96 * df$se

plot(df$prediction ~ c(1:5), ylim = c(0,1), 
     pch = 19, ylab = "Predicted Probability",xlab = "Enhancement of enviromental policies (c2c)",
     main = "Figure 6: Predicted Pr(Y = 1) by c2c")
segments(c(1:5), df$lower, c(1:5), df$upper)
text(x = c(1.25,4.75), par("usr")[3],labels = c("Strongly disagree","Strongly agree"),
     pos= 3)

try(dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"]),silent=TRUE)
try(dev.off(),silent=TRUE)

rm(df, se)

#Predicted probabilites & CIs c2g
df <- data.frame(e1 = mean(dat_clear$e1), e2 = mean(dat_clear$e2),
                 e4 = mean(dat_clear$e4), c2a = mean(dat_clear$c2a),
                 c2b = mean(dat_clear$c2b), c2c = mean(dat_clear$c2c), 
                 c2g = min(dat_clear$c2g) : max(dat_clear$c2g))

head(df)

se <- predict(m3, newdata = df, type = "response",
              se.fit = TRUE)
str(se)
df$prediction <- se$fit
df$se <- se$se.fit

df$lower <- df$prediction - 1.96 * df$se
df$upper <- df$prediction + 1.96 * df$se

plot(df$prediction ~ c(1:5), ylim = c(0,1), 
     pch = 19, ylab = "Predicted Probability",xlab = "Welfare state (c2g)",
     main = "Figure 7: Predicted Pr(Y = 1) by c2g")
segments(c(1:5), df$lower, c(1:5), df$upper)
text(x = c(1.25,4.75), par("usr")[3],labels = c("Strongly disagree","Strongly agree"),
     pos= 3)

try(dev.off(dev.list()["RStudioGD"]),silent=TRUE)
try(dev.off(),silent=TRUE)

rm(df, se)
```

Comment: You can do it very easily in the Terminal with **ImageMagick** like this `montage image1.png image2.png image3.png image4.png -geometry +5+5 result.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` ?

```r
png("multiplot.png", width = 640, height = 640)
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
for(i in 1:4) plot(rnorm(50), rnorm(50), col = i, 
                   xlab = "x", ylab = "y", main = paste("plot", i))
dev.off()
```

Which results in:

**multiplot.png**

[image]

You simply open the png device, set it's graphical parameters with `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` and then each of the next four plots you make are put on the same image. After four plots are drawn, call `dev.off()` to save the image.